# How to configure protractor cucumber report along with screenshots with typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, report

I have gone through many tutorials but could not find the process for configuring protractor with cucumber reports along with screenshot in typescript.
Can you help me with the configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can get screenshots on Test case failures with jasmine2-protractor-utils. 
Install the npm plugin.

```
npm install jasmine2-protractor-utils -g
```

Add the below snippet in config file :

```
    exports.config = {
    plugins: [{
    package: 'jasmine2-protractor-utils',
    disableHTMLReport: false,
    disableScreenshot: true,
    screenshotPath: './reports/screenshots',
    screenshotOnExpectFailure: true,
    screenshotOnSpecFailure: true,
    clearFoldersBeforeTest: true,
    htmlReportDir: './reports/htmlReports',
  }],
  onPrepare: function() {
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      consolidateAll: true,
      savePath: './Results',
      filePrefix: 'xmlresults-test1'
    }));
  },
  onComplete: function() {
   var browserName, browserVersion;
   var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

   capsPromise.then(function(caps) {
    browserName = caps.get('browserName');
    browserVersion = caps.get('version');
    platform = caps.get('platform');

    var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');

    testConfig = {
     reportTitle: 'Protractor Test Execution Report',
     outputPath: './reports',
     outputFilename: 'ProtractorTestReport',
     screenshotPath: './reports/screenshots',
     testBrowser: browserName,
     browserVersion: browserVersion,
     modifiedSuiteName: true,
     screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
     testPlatform: platform
   };
   new HTMLReport().from('./Results/xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
  });
 }
```

Comment: Im looking for protractor-cucumber reporting not for jasmine

Answer (score 0):

For protractor-cucumber-framework, I use [cucumber-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter)

And then in my after hook, I have this to take screenshots if the scenario failed.

```
const world = this;
if (scenario.result.status === 'failed') {
    if (!scenario.result.exception.message.includes('No database result found')) {
        await browser.takeScreenshot().then(buffer => {
            return world.attach(buffer, 'image/png');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for the cucumber html report with typescript

Comment: @priyanka bonam it is for cucumber html report with typescript

Comment: Can you please help me with the configuration to be done

Comment: It's literally in the link that I commented.